# Why we should have $\frac{dR}{d\alpha}=0$ to have the expression independent from $\alpha$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463811/how-do-you-simplify-an-expression-involving-fourth-and-higher-order-trigonometri), I have the expression $R=\sin^6\alpha +\cos^6\alpha +K(\sin^4\alpha +\cos^4\alpha )$ and the purpose of that question is finding the value of $K$ so that $R$ become independent to $\alpha$.

As suggested in the comments , one way is setting $\frac{dR}{d\alpha}=0$ and find $K$. but I don't know why having $\frac{dR}{d\alpha}=0$, make expression become independent of $\alpha$. I know if we take derivative of a function with respect to a constant (a number) it is equal to zero, but I can't make a connection to this problem because treating $\alpha$ as a constant doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's not saying that $\alpha$ is a constant - rather, if the derivative is zero, then $R$ is a constant, not involving $\alpha$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, Oh I see. thank you very much!